# Accessing text of selected drop-down list option using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

This should so be so very, very simple, but I can't seem to find a straight-forward answer.

I have a drop-down list that I'm populating like this:

```
<select ng-model="SelectedItem.RegulationId" id="ddlRegulation" name="ddlRegulation" ng-options="reg.Id as reg.Title for reg in Regulations"></select>
```

Now, all I want to do, in the save() function I've set up (which has access to $scope, BTW), is simply display for the user the text of the option they chose.

Something like:

```
alert($scope.SelectedItem.Regulations.Title);
```

Or

```
alert($scope.ddlRegulation.text());
```

I just don't know enough about AngularJS to know where I should be looking for this property. I suppose I could just import the jQuery library and do it that way, but I suspect there's an easy way to do this with AngularJS that I just don't know about yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use object as model, not id (And remove crap name and id):

```
<select ng-model="SelectedItem.Regulation" ng-options="reg as reg.Title for reg in Regulations"></select>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/kBbfJgi3ysNptskniyXA

Comment: And then use $scope.SelectedItem.Regulations.Title to access the text?

Comment: Ah, I should have explained. The main model is Citation, and Regulation is a sub-collection. If I use ng-model="SelectedItem.Regulation" the save method actually inserts a new Regulation record along with the Citation record, instead of just saving a Citation record with a Citation.RegulationId property.

Comment: You can: 1. Make ng-model="zzzZZZ" Add to select: ng-change="SelectedItem.RegulationId = zzzZZZ.Id". 2. Change your model Citation to have object not Id. 3. Retrieve title by id from Regulations array

Comment: Hi I know this is pretty old post. Did you find an answer for this? I have a similar form with select field and I am trying to access the selected option in the angular js controller but unable to do so. It would be really great if someone can answer `<select id="eventtype1" ng-model="formdata.eventtype1" class="form-control" ng-options='eventtype1 for eventtype1 in eventType'> </select>` but when I try to access the value in controller using `console.log($scope.formdata.eventtype1);` i get undefined.